# intermittent net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET error

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, tomcat, network-programming, tomcat7

I have a webpage that makes a POST request to a URL on a Tomcat web server. 99% of the time this all works fine however every month or 2 we get a few *external* users for whom the request does not get sent.  In Chrome the error is net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET.  This means that our web server does not even receive the request or log anything.

The interesting thing is that this error is not only intermittent but it seems to re-occur for only a handful of users. There are also people in the same network as the users experiencing the problem that are *not* experiencing the problem. I have never been able to reproduce this on any browser or machine. After a while (a few days maybe) the problem will go away and everything will be fine for a month or two.

Can anyone provide some more information about what might be causing this error?  Everything I find online indicates that it's most likely a network problem on the client side but I don't know how to confirm this so that I can guide their IT in making the appropriate change to prevent this in the future. Could this ultimately be caused on the server side?  If this is a server side issue even better because then I could fix it on my end and prevent for other users.

Comment: A connection reset doesn't necessarily mean that your web server doesn't receive the request, but that it terminates the connection before a response is (completely) sent. You'd have to reproduce the problem and watch your server logs to see if a client request arrives at your server or not.

Comment: In this particular case nothing makes it to our web server (tomcat).  I am in contact with the client so I know approximately when they send the request but there is nothing in the log.

Comment: Allright. And there's no webserver in front of tomcat, like Apache with mod_jk? Btw, windows updates seem to happen every two months or so, might be related. Maybe their router's NAT tables get flooded.

Comment: have you resolved the same?

Comment: if any update, please share